# Providing more specificity to route resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, custom-routes

I have two lines in my routes.rb that look like this:

```
  resources :locations
  get '/locations/:session_series_token/new', to: 'locations#new', as: "new_location"
```

I want the `create` method in my LocationsController, and I also want a specific `locations#new` path.

Removing the `resources :locations` line causes my `#new` form to error with:

```
undefined method `locations_path' for #<<Class:0x007fa18caeb3b8>:0x007fa18caea8f0>
Extracted source (around line #1):

  <%= form_for [@location] do |form| %>
    <h2>Class Location</h2>
```

There must be a way to do this correctly!

Answer (score 0):

I think that since you are removing `resources: locations` there is no longer an "index" route for Location (called locations_path). Run the command `rake routes` and you will see that you are only left with a new_location_path.

Try specifying the path like so:

```
<%= form_for @location, url: new_location_path do |form| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
resources :locations, except: [:new]
get '/locations/:session_series_token/new', to: 'locations#new', as: "new_location"
```

As the `resources :locations` defines all the routes for you and you need to define only the `new` route explicitly so you can write like above. If you remove the `resources :locations` then your `create` route also gets removed and the line `<%= form_for [@location] do |form| %>` searches for the `locations_path` which is the `create` action.

Hope this helps.